# Program that runs in C++, it then calls functions in a Python file. It runs just fine, but the program ends to soon

Tags: python, c++

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void CallProcedure(string pName)
{
    char* procname = new char[pName.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, pName.c_str());

    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* my_module = PyImport_ImportModule("PythonCode");
    PyErr_Print();
    PyObject* my_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(my_module, procname);
    PyObject* my_result = PyObject_CallObject(my_function, NULL);
    Py_Finalize();

    delete[] procname;
}



int callIntFunc(string proc, string param)
{
    char* procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    char* paramval = new char[param.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(paramval, param.c_str());


    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue = nullptr, * presult = nullptr;
    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PythonCode");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(z)", paramval);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    Py_Finalize();

    delete[] procname;
    delete[] paramval;


    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}

int callIntFunc(string proc, int param)
{
    char* procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue = nullptr, * presult = nullptr;
    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PythonCode");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(i)", param);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    Py_Finalize();

    delete[] procname;

    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}

boolean PrintMenuOptions() {
    int input;
    while (true) {
        cout << "1: Display a Multiplication Table" << endl << "2: Double a Value" << endl << "3: Exit" << endl << "Enter your selection as a number 1, 2, or 3." << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 1) {
            int value = 0;
            system("cls");
            cout << "Please enter a number for multiplication table!" << endl;
            cin >> value;
            system("cls");
            callIntFunc("MultiplicationTable", value); //ENDS HERE

            //DOES NOT RUN THIS BELOW!!!! 
            cout << "Would you like to rerun program? Y or N" << endl;
            char yn;
            cin >> yn;
            if (yn == 'n' || yn == 'N')
                return false;
            return true;
        }




        else if (input == 2) {
            system("cls");
            int value = 0;
            cout << "Please enter a number to double!" << endl;
            cin >> value;
            cout << value << " X 2 = " << callIntFunc("DoubleValue", value);
            // Call double a value
        }

        else if (input == 3) {
            break;
        }

        else {
            system("cls");
            cout << "You did not enter 1, 2, or 3! Try again!" << endl;
        }
        
    }
}



void main()
{
PrintMenuOptions();

}
```

C++ File ^^

Python File:

```
import re
import string


def printsomething():
    print("Hello from python!")

def PrintMe(v):
    print("You sent me: " + v)
    return 100;

def SquareValue(v):
    return v * v

def MultiplicationTable(value):
     for x in range(1,11):
         print(value, " X ", x , " = " , value * x)

def DoubleValue(value):
    return value * 2
```

I made a file in C++ that calls functions within a Python file.This program works just fine but I would like the user to be able to return to the menu after calling one of the options.I set up the menu function in my C++ file which runs a while (true) loop around the whole menu so you can repeat the menu after the user uses a menu function but the program breaks the loopand ends after calling the python file function. I made comments where the program stops running.

Comment: Are any of the lines inside `callIntFunc()` executed before the program ends?  If so, which ones?

Comment: @JohnGordon -- No, he calls them from the C++ code.  That's the point.

Comment: Have you single-stepped through this in a debugger to see what happens?  Does the Python call return?  Do you get an error code, or an exit code?  Which operating system?

Comment: @TimRoberts it runs to line "return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);" inside the function int callIntFunc(string proc, int param) in the C++ code. I get                             
                 "Unhandled exception at 0x000000005138598B (python36.dll) in WeekSixAssignment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000050."I do have that .dll file in my x64 release file.

Comment: Fixed, needed to return something in Python functions.

Comment: Was the problem that `PyCallable_Check(func)` was returning false, so `presult` was never set to a non-NULL value, so then `_PyLong_AsInt(presult)` would end up dereferencing the NULL pointer that was passed in as its argument?  (or perhaps `PyObject_CallObject()` was returning NULL instead?)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner ended up being a easy fix, I just had to return something within the def MultiplicationTable(value): function.... This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @ColeBaxendale you might want to consider what will happen the next time someone (possibly you) forgets to return something from their Python script... do you want your program to crash in that case, or handle the error more gracefully, e.g. by printing out an informative error message to stderr?